# "External ID standard field" vs "Custom field with the External ID and Unique attributes"

Tags: salesforce

**CONTEXT**:

Salesforce External objects/relationships.

The below table is taken from Salesforce documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_object_relationships.htm&type=5

[image]

**QUESTIONS:**

What is "External ID standard field"?

Can you provide an example?

Thank you very much!